Client Fails to Connect to Server on Initial Attempt but Succeeds After Restart ( when the computer is first turned on )
I have developed a small server-client (server: python client: c#) application running on localhost and port 6000. When I start my computer, the client fails to connect to the server on the first attempt. However, if I close and reopen the application, the connection is successful/
Server:
def start_server():
    
    host, port = "localhost", 6000
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))

    server_socket.listen(1)
    print("\nServer is waiting...")
    connection, address = server_socket.accept()
    
    return connection

Client:
private void ConnectToServer() {
    client = new TcpClient();
    try {
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6000);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}


Your start_server method only accepts a single connection, which is unusual. You should close the listening socket after the last connection has been accepted, so before you do return connection you need to call server_socket.close(). It may be that a previous server instance was still running when you tried to connect with the client.

From cmd.exe >Netstat -a  Check if TCP port 6000 is being used before starting.  I think what is happening is the port is already being used and first time is creating an exception in app that is using the port and forcing the app to close.

Use the socket and threading modules in Python to handle multiple clients. The server will accept connections and spawn a new thread for each client to handle communication independently.
Python TCP Server
import socket
import threading

# Function to handle client communication
def handle_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive data from client
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            # Print received data
            print(f"Received: {data.decode('utf-8')}")

            # Echo the data back to the client
            client_socket.sendall(data)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Connection reset by client.")
            break
    client_socket.close()

def start_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=65432):
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to the address and port
    server_socket.bind((host, port))

    # Listen for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")
    
    while True:
        # Accept a new connection
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connected to {addr}")

        # Create a new thread to handle the client
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_handler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()

C# TCP Client
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class TcpClientExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 65432;

        try
        {
            // Create a TCP client
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverAddress, serverPort))
            {
                // Get the network stream
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                while (true)
                {
                    // Read user input
                    Console.Write("Enter message to send (or 'exit' to quit): ");
                    string message = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (message.ToLower() == "exit")
                        break;

                    // Convert message to bytes and send it
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                    // Read the server's response
                    data = new byte[256];
                    int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    string responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Received from server: {responseData}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

